# Visual C# - What sort of form control should I use for this task?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm looking for suggestions as to what type of form control, or what combination of form controls I should use for the following task:

I have a list of files that all need to be renamed, and the new name must be typed in manually.  I essentially need to display the list of files, and provide a text box for renaming.  I prefer that all files, and their new name are displayed all at once, instead of a list of files, with 1 text box that updates when you click on the file in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sounds like a datagridview would work; one column for the old name, one column for the new name, and a 'commit' button to rename them all at once

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) which shows the file names in one column and has a textbox in the next column which allows you to enter the new file name.